# PhoneGap.Build example com.facebook.sdk error 2

Tags: phonegap-plugins, facebook-ios-sdk, phonegap-build

Bulding via phonegap.build service simple example(https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/tree/master/example/Simple) from this repo + my config.xml (https://gist.github.com/zulman/5070388)

After tap on login button message informs me about "com.facebook.sdk error 2"

I check all info on github's main page about this error, check stackoverflow entries.

- My bundle id is the same on facebook dev page and in config.
- My sandbox mode disabled on facebook dev page.
- My app ids are equal on js, config and facebook dev page.

How i can get extended error info or way to fix it without using manual building on xcode? Thanks.

Comment: Its strange but after changing iOS key on build.phonegap.com and changing facebook app error disappeared.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by changing the iOS key? I don't use phonegap build - I build cordova locally. Also, changing facebook APP, do you mean you created a new APP? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.
Check the permissions you are requesting.
Apparently with the newest version of SDK you cannot request write and read permissions during the same request.

For me, requesting "offline_access" was an issue. After removing that one, the error disappeared. Try requesting only the basic permissions (like "email,user_about_me") and see what happens.